# Google Maps API - Slow loading javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using Google Maps API to display a map on a certain page.

Problem is that the file `http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api.....` sometimes happens to load very slow - decreasing the page's performance, because the rest of the JavaScript is first loaded on document ready, which its rarely reaches - because the browser locks up waiting for the file from Google.

I have tried to move the JavaScript file from the `<head>` tag to under my content. But the rest of the JavaScript is never fired because the browser waits for the file from Google.

Is there a way around this, or have anyone else experienced same problem? It began recently, and I have no idea why.

This is my code, if anyone is interested:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=ABQIAAAAa24xicak8_ghHX58i7La7hRFh9iM79SNC94rOejOtdMRvQmJiBS6Uv5F_1BNSh9ZuSzFXyekHISgew">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/maps.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Google Maps
    initialize();

    // Other JavaScript comes here....

   });
</script>
```

If I access

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=ABQIAAAAa24xicak8_ghHX58i7La7hRFh9iM79SNC94rOejOtdMRvQmJiBS6Uv5F_1BNSh9ZuSzFXyekHISgew
```

The file loads instantly.

Comment: Are you using Firebug?  I found that firebug decreased the performance of my app when I was working with the maps api, and if i viewed the page on a browser without firebug it was fine.

Comment: I've seen the same thing, but only in firefox and when running against localhost. IE and Chrome have been fine.

Comment: I am using Firebug to debug. I can try switching it off and see if it helps.

Comment: Disabling firebug fixed the problem! This is weird. Firebug have been running the past weeks with no problem at all. Thanks Paul - you can answer this post and I accept yours.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a rather old question now - the solution was to disable firebug (atleast for me).

Comment: Yes, for me too, I was investigating in both FF and IE9, and when closed the Firebug in FF and Developer Tools in IE9 the map get loaded, thx!

Answer (score 12):

Use Google's Ajax APIs. From some time past, all of Google's services can be accessed through the JavaScript API. It's a modular system, you only have to include the JSAPI library, and then you can dynamically load the modules you need—it won't block your site.

```
<script type="text/javascript"        
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABCDEFG"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("maps", "2");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    // Your logic goes here.
    // It will be run right after the maps module was loaded.
});
</script>
```

For further details, see [JSAPI's developer documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/).

Answer (score 4):

On JavaScript optimization: always put your JS at the bottom of your  even your Maps API script. I can't really think of any good reason to have any JS in the head.

Comment: I know this is old but if you're using google maps api or require.js, both of those recommend you put it at the top.

Comment: I haven't had issues with it at the bottom for both.

Comment: If you put your javascript at the bottom, it won't run until after the page has rendered, which is undesirable in a number of scenarios.

Comment: because it's supposed to be in the head ! only recently programmers started to move their scripts to the body. i still think the scripts should be in the head, compiled early, but initialized later. just because i don't like to mix content and source code.