# Google Maps Javascript API mobile performance issue

Tags: javascript, android, performance, mobile, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to build a mobile application using Google Maps Javascript API v3. Functionally, it's doing fine, but the performance is really sluggish on middleware Android devices (used Samsung Galaxy 3 for testing).
I also checked the performance on the official http://maps.google.com, had the same result, and using  the [first example code](http://code.google.com/intl/hu/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple.html) as well. Is there any mobile specific step, I might have missed (see the example code), or the Javascript API performance is limited to this level, and building a native application cannot be avoided in this case?

Thank you very much for the answers!

Here is the code of the linked page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: would love to see some sort of answer on this one!

Comment: Did you try putting your script and the bottom?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have a performance as good as a native app using it, but I can't prove that to you. It's more like an opinion than an answer. Good luck with that! :)

Comment: Perhaps this can be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875678/google-maps-api-slow-loading-javascript

Comment: When you say performance is bad, is it that it takes too much time to load or once loaded, the interactions are sluggish?

Comment: Have you tried m.google.com/maps ? That's the official mobile version of google maps, if that one is slow, then it is slow :)

Answer (score 9):

As per [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics), your code is right. And maps is optimized.

I suggest:

1. Try to change the script URL to `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false`
2. Load scripts at end of page.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Try the demo out at http://fiddle.jshell.net/tomasdev/8FhYz/show/light/ — I'm in doubt regarding your device. If official demos work slow, I don't think there is a quite good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Google maps performance is VERY MUCH dependant on how well structured the whole page is.

The biggest performance hit usually comes from repaint/render cycles of the page - caused by the tiles loading / unloading.

Dependant on how the map is placed and how you use it, it's a benefit to position the map element using position:fixed, taking it out of the document flow. Position:absolute can also help, but not as much as 'fixed'.